# Only wifi device that cant ping other wifi devices, but can connect to internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I just set up a laptop with unbuntu xenial and can browse the internet when connected to wifi, can ping devices that are plugged into the router but  cannot ping other devices that are connected via wifi even though they can ping each other. All devices are on the same subnet and can ping each other without an issue. When I plug my computer into the router i can ping the other wifi devices fine.

This is my first time diving into the linux so apologies of this is rather basic.

Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: Can other devices connected by WiFi ping each other? Are you the network administrator? If not, can  you ask the network administrator whether the LAN permits WiFi devices to communicate with each other?

Comment: Yeah the other wifi devices can ping one another fine (don't know why I forgot that part) which is where i get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

your wifi access point may have client isolation turned on. Sometimes called station isolation or similar. It stop wifi clients talking to each other. The idea being improved client security on a shared wifi network.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the other devices connected via wifi can communicate with one another just fine.

Comment: any host firewalls on any of the clients involved ?